# Range по словарю вместо множества if при использовании цикла for

Tags: python, if, for, словарь, range

Изучаю Python, и в данный момент пишу программу для анализа данных с браслета MiBand.

Столкнулся с тем, что код выглядит довольно громоздко, и хочу заменить множество повторений if на range по списку. Для того, чтобы код выглядел более компактно.
Так же, если разберусь в этим моментом, то смогу делать более детальную аналитику.

Данные берутся из csv файла, и проходит проверка по дате. Если дата совпадает с конкретным месяцем, до данные записываются в словарь. А затем использую данные для подсчёта статистики.

Находил информацию о switch. Но, что-то в данный момент не могу разобраться с кем как switch работает.

Так же в моей программе, есть подобный код для вычисления статистики по часам. Так, сам цикл for там занимает уже 48 строчек кода.

Собственно вопрос, как вместо названия месяцев, пройти циклом по списку?

```
month_stat_steps = {
'январь': [], 'февраль': [], 'март': [], 'апрель': [], 'май': [], 'июнь': [],
'июль': [], 'август': [], 'сентябрь': [], 'октябрь': [], 'ноябрь': [], 'декабрь': [],
}
```

`file_reader_steps_copy = list(file_reader_steps)`

```
        for row in file_reader_steps_copy:
        # Забираем данные по месяцам
        if row['date'][5:-3] == '01':
            month_stat_steps['январь'].append(int(row['steps']))
        if row['date'][5:-3] == '02':
            month_stat_steps['февраль'].append(int(row['steps']))
        if row['date'][5:-3] == '03':
            month_stat_steps['март'].append(int(row['steps']))
        if row['date'][5:-3] == '04':
            month_stat_steps['апрель'].append(int(row['steps']))
```

Comment: Вам нужно более подробно описать задачу. И попробуйте изучить библиотеку `Pandas`, там всё гораздо проще делается что касается данных в `csv`.

Comment: Спасибо. Поскольку недавно начал изучать Python, и многие технологии для меня еще не известны. Так и думаю, что есть много простых решений у моего вопроса.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно как-то так с помощью `enumerate` всё дополнительным циклом сделать:

```
for row in file_reader_steps_copy:
    # Забираем данные по месяцам
    for i, month in enumerate(month_stat_steps, 1):
        if row['date'][5:-3] == f'{i:02}':
            month_stat_steps[month].append(int(row['steps']))
```

Comment: Спасибо, заработало с помощью ctrl+c и ctrl+v. Теперь пойду разбираться как именно работает этот код, чтобы вставить и в другие места :).

Comment: Примерно понял как работает. Enumerate, похож на range, а проверку делаем с помощью форматного текста f'{i:02}'.

Comment: Да, `enumerate(month_stat_steps)` это что-то типа `zip(range(1, len(month_stat_steps)+1), month_stat_steps)` только короче )